# Where does one find documentation for the MtGox trade API?

Tags: mtgox, api

I find a lot of references to it, ruby-wrappers etc., but where can one find actual documentation for the MtGox API?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6133/is-there-any-useful-documentation-on-using-the-mtgox-api-with-node-js

Comment: I rephrased the title of the question, since it seemed to me that you were more interested in where to find documentation rather then whether one exists. Please review whether the edit fits your intent, otherwise you may role it back, or improve it to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is their [documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v2) for their http based api and here is their [documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming) for the websockets based one.

There are many wrappers in many languages already written.

- [Ruby](https://github.com/sferik/mtgox)
- [Node.js](https://npmjs.org/package/mtgox)
- [Python](https://github.com/goncalopp/python-mtgox)

just to name a few